# CUPS authentication issue when printing to thermal printer connected to Pi

Tags: raspbian, linux, login, printing, cups

I have this Adafruit Mini Thermal printer connected to a Pi running Raspbian Jesse. I have CUPS installed on the Pi and can print directly to the printer without any issues.

But when I try to print to it from a different Linux server, all jobs fail. I have CUPS installed on the Linux server as well and the Pi printer connected over IPP. `Printers.conf` on the Linux server:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.4.2
# Written by cupsd on 2017-07-05 11:05
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter ZJ-58>
AuthInfoRequired none
Info ZJ-58
DeviceURI ipp://10.10.102.62/printers/ZJ-58
State Idle
StateTime 1499227494
Type 6
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

When I check `/var/log/cups/error_log`, I see this:

```
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/ipp (PID 31328)
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] 1 files to send in job...
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Connecting to 10.10.102.62:631
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Connecting to printer...
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Connected to printer...
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Connected to 10.10.102.62:631 (IPv4)...
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Getting supported attributes...
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] ATTR: auth-info-required=none
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Backend returned status 2 (authentication required)
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] Job held for authentication.
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] End of messages
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] printer-state=3(idle)
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] printer-state-message="/usr/lib/cups/backend/ipp failed"
D [05/Jul/2017:11:04:54 +0700] [Job 10] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Looks like authentication (or the failure of) is blocking printouts. I've turned off Authentication on both Pi and the Linux server by changing `DefaultAuthType` to `none` in `cupsd.conf` and restarted the cups daemon on both.

Still nothing prints. Any ideas?

Thank you.